# Add user (to create home directory) on a remote computer, from an Active Directory in VB

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

Is it possible, in VB, to add a user (form AD) on a remote computer, without having the user password. The goal is to create the user home directory, to transfert his/her files from the old computer to the new one.

Thanks

I tried searching for the solution but all I could find is how to create an AD user on the server.